# Какие есть библиотеки с emoji для android приложения?

Tags: java, android, поиск-библиотек, android-library

Нужна библиотека, чтобы реализовать всплывающую клавиатуру с эмодзи по нажатию кнопки и возможность установить кастомные эмодзи.

Вот [пример](https://github.com/Aghajari/AXEmojiView) о чем я говорю.

К сожалению, она уже старая как и многие другие, но это был самый наилучший вариант, который к сожалению не удалось настроить и довести до ума.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый нажав на галку слева от него.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно использовать [библиотеку](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/text-and-emoji/emoji-compat#downloadable-fonts-supplib-dependency) от Google. Добавляем зависимость:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation "androidx.emoji:emoji:28.0.0"
}
```

инициализируем конфигурацию:

```
val fontRequest = FontRequest(
                "com.example.fontprovider",
                "com.example",
                "emoji compat Font Query",
                CERTIFICATES
        )
val config = FontRequestEmojiCompatConfig(this, fontRequest)
EmojiCompat.init(config)
```

понятие кастомности эмодзи не очень понятно, так как это просто сочетание символов, и думаю что если их нету в стандартной поддержке, то вы их сами будете должны нарисовать. Для своего виджета подключение библиотеки происходит так:

```
class MyTextView(context: Context) : AppCompatTextView(context) {

    private val emojiTextViewHelper: EmojiTextViewHelper by lazy(LazyThreadSafetyMode.NONE) {
        EmojiTextViewHelper(this).apply {
            updateTransformationMethod()
        }
    }

    override fun setFilters(filters: Array<InputFilter>) {
        super.setFilters(emojiTextViewHelper.getFilters(filters))
    }

    override fun setAllCaps(allCaps: Boolean) {
        super.setAllCaps(allCaps)
        emojiTextViewHelper.setAllCaps(allCaps)
    }
}
```

вот [полезный туториал](https://proandroiddev.com/how-to-create-a-basic-emoji-keyboard-in-android-c7e3e9eb99f3) по данной тематике.

### UPDATE

Библиотека выше deprecated, вместо нее гугл предлагает использовать данную эмодзи зависимость - [Emoji2](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/emoji2). Если же хочется получить +/- готовое решение, то можно воспользоваться таким [вариантом](https://github.com/vanniktech/Emoji)